# popup / banner - on click disappears banner and if the user reloads the page does not see banner if until closing and reopening browers

Tags: javascript, html

my name is Andrea can you help me please?
I have a banner that I show with some text and if the user clicks it it closes but the problem is:

if I reload the page the banner reappears and does not remain closed as clicked on the X button

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function(){
        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
        .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
        return false;
    };
};
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="close"><h4>X</h4></button>
  <p class="card-title text-white">configurazione di Seo Tools Manager</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't spam tag.

Comment: Hello Andrea, welcome to Stack Overflow! Before asking a question, please make sure to do some basic research and try to generalize your question a bit. I think your question is how to make a web page memorize things across reloads. Please look up "cookies": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser doesn't automatically remember if a user closed the banner. You have to use, for example, `localStorage` to save that action in the user's browser so, when the page is reloaded, the browser "remembers" that that user closed the banner in the past.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var popup = document.querySelector('.card-body');
  // Check if the user has previously closed the banner and display/hide it accordingly
  if (!localStorage.getItem('closedBanner')) {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }

  document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
    // Save into the user's browser that the popup was closed
    localStorage.setItem('closedBanner', "true");

    this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
      .removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    return false;
  };
};
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <button id="close"><h4>X</h4></button>
  <p class="card-title text-white">configurazione di Seo Tools Manager</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi
ajmnz, thank you for your time and help .. thanks again

Comment: ok if instead I had more banners with the same style but with a different ID like this? if I set the javascript above it works and the banner closes but then I close all the other 4 too .. there is a way to remember 4 different banners

Comment: <button id="close"><h4>X</h4></button>

Comment: <button id="close-user"><h4>X</h4></button>

Comment: <button id="close-invoice"><h4>X</h4></button>

Comment: <div class="card-body">

Comment: only the different banner changes but then the class is the same as you could do to remember the 4 different banners but with the same class

Comment: You would just need to store different values for each banner. Something like `closedBanner1`, `closedBanner2`, and so on. Just repeat the process for each banner and change the item name (`closedBanner`) for something different.
Got it?

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer I ask you something .. I used "closedBanner2" closedBanner1 ... but the banner always has the .card-body CLASS and if I click to close not so xk

Comment: the banner is html it is the same as the one above it changes only the text I show but the class and action is the same instead the javascript I used your code and it works but if I close the 1 banner it disappears but if I close the banner 2,3 ... copy to the page reload

Comment: Could you provide some code or the link to the website? JSFiddle will do